# How do I load elements from a http site and add it to my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

We want to load `html` element from a `url` and add it to our website (or replace a current element)

We have tried:

```
document.getELementById("content").innerHTML = url;
```

This works with images but we want to load just an element not the whole page

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to make an HTTP request to the server and get the content first.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'your-url-here';

request.onload = function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = request.responseText;
};

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send();
```

Comment: One quesstion: what is this.responseText in this case?

Comment: @user3194181 The response from the server in this case the `this` keyword references the `request` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery with `load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to achieve something like that **after** asking for permission from the admins of the site where you're stealing from.

"Stealing" might sound a bit harsh for you but that's how the admins of the other site will see it. If they notice what you're doing, your server will be added to their firewall under the `BLOCKED` section.

Note that if the other site is running on a different domain, trying to do this JavaScript will fail because of the [Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). In that case, you'll have to add code to your own server which gets the data from the other site and offer it in a useful form to your own JavaScript running in the client (like using jQuery's `load()` function).

If your server is written in JavaScript, [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) is your friend.

Comment: I don't think you can even do that because of the same origin policy. Check out the "Additional Notes" section of the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just copy the code with the inspect element tool, but that is considered wrong.